# What are the pros and cons of starting learning a language in different script from your native language in your own script?

Tags: writing-system

My native language uses Latin alphabet. If I want to start learning another language which uses another script as an adult, e.g. Chinese or Thai, I could start by learning the Chinese / Thai script first, and then slowly improve from there, like I presume a child learning it as their first language.

Or another option, since I already have another script (i.e. Latin) down pat, is I can learn and build a base Chinese / Thai vocab in its romanized spelling first (e.g in the case of Chinese, using Hanyu Pinyin), and pick up the spelling / writing in Chinese / Thai script later.

What's the pros and cons of the latter approach?

Comment: So you are not learning or needing to use Chinese characters? I would only consider using romanized language if your goal is speech or quick learning only.

Comment: This is another example of an opinion-based question, which I think can be easily adapted to an objective question. Rather than asking what one *should* do, can you ask for the pros and cons of the different approaches?" Then the answer no longer depends on your specific (probably unknown) situation, and can apply to any future visitor with a similar question, but different circumstances. E.g. "What are the pros and cons sides to initially learning Chinese using a Latin alphabet?"

Comment: I guess I can adapt the question. But I'm also curious, in the end is it subjective, i.e. different method works for different persons?

Also I will clarify that the scope for the question is at the beginning of the learning journey.

Comment: Edited; feel free to edit also to improve it further.

Comment: By asking for pros and cons, you cover the "subjective basis." An answer can say "For some people, it's good because X, while other struggle with Y."

Comment: @Flimzy When you say this should be a generalized "pros and cons" question, I visualize answers that will either be too broad or opinion based. Because a general question will result in a general answer. On the contrary, in line with the Q/A format used on SE, questions should be as *specific* as possible. This will allow specific answers. So I would prefer to see questions with as much detail as appropriate. In this question, actual example words or phrases that illustrate the OP's problem would be an improvement. As you say, (probably unknown) refers to this lack of detail.

Comment: @user3169: That can be another approach, and in some cases it is probably better. But often having a list of pros/cons is going to be far more useful, not to mention *possible*. Describing ones' own situation in sufficient detail to provide a prescriptive answer often isn't possible or practical.

Comment: @user3169 not sure if what you meant by actual example words is eg mentioning that I learnt "have dinner" in Chinese first as "Chī wǎnfàn" before learning later on it's written as "吃晚饭"? I'm not sure how that can help make it easier to answer (I'm interested in applying it to starting learning a language, not this phrase or any particular phrase), but if it can help answerers I can always edit it in.

Comment: Pretty close. If I understand your intent, the question here could be "When learning Chinese vocabulary, should I learn the romanized equivalent (Chī wǎnfàn) first, or learn the actual kanji (吃晚饭) from the beginning?". Also then one can see that you are not really just using (I assume western) alpha characters, because of all the diacritical mark forms that are technically new to the learner.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the ones with diacritic; in actual case I started with a different notation system for the romanization ( chi1 wan3fan4 ), so example may be misleading. And in any case, I was thinking of a more generalized case where the native language may not be western; e.g. if a Japanese wants to learn English, what's the pros and cons of learning from katakana first, rather than straight to Latin alphabets?